# FreeMemory and CPUUsage get memory leaks and system out of memory

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, perfmon

```
private float FreeMemory
{
    get { return _nFreeMemory; }
    set
    {
        _nFreeMemory = value;
        statusBarPanelMem.Text = _nFreeMemory + " MB prosto";
    }
}

private int CPUUsage
{
    get { return _nCpuUsage; }
    set
    {
        _nCpuUsage = value;
        statusBarPanelCPU.Text = "CPU poraba " + _nCpuUsage + "%";
    }
}
```

Then I am using Timer and calling

```
private void InitialiseCounterRamNetwork()
{
    _cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", true);
    _ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", true);
}

private void timerMemProcNetwork_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FreeMemory = _ramCounter.NextValue();
   CPUUsage = Convert.ToInt32(_cpuCounter.NextValue());
}
```

But becouse of this i get memory leaks and system out of memory exceptions. Why GC doesn't collect this?

Comment: Make it clear: does this reproduce the problem in an empty app, without the rest of your code? How fast is the Timer running?

Answer (score 1):

Not reproducable (Fx 4.5).

The listed code does not cause any memory leak.